# Error when trying to install SSIS 2005 Package on 64 bit OS

Tags: ssis

I've created an SSIS package on a 64 bit Windows 7 box running the 32 bit version of SQL Server 2005. When I try to install the package on a 64 bit Windows Server 2008 box running the 32 bit version of SQL Server 2005 I get the following error:

```
===================================

Unexpected error occurred. (Package Installation Wizard)

===================================

Retrieving the COM class factory for component with CLSID {E44847F1-FD8C-4251-B5DA-B04BB22E236E} 

failed due to the following error: 80040154. (Microsoft.SqlServer.ManagedDTS)

------------------------------
Program Location:

at Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime.Application..ctor()
at Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Deployment.PackageInstallationWizardForm..ctor()
at Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Deployment.PackageInstaller.Main(String[] args)

===================================

Retrieving the COM class factory for component with CLSID {E44847F1-FD8C-4251-B5DA-B04BB22E236E} 

failed due to the following error: 80040154. (Microsoft.SqlServer.ManagedDTS)

------------------------------
Program Location:

at Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime.Application..ctor()
```

I've also tried to install it on my Windows 7 box and got the same error. I have the same version of SQL Server 2005 running on our test server which is running 64 bit Windows Server 2003 and the installation wizard launches just fine.

On the Server 2003 box there isn't an assemblies folder in the C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\90\SDK so even though it's a 32 bit install of SQL Server the install is different. I'm figuring it was an upgrade from a previous version.

So far through my research I haven't found anything that's helped me correct this issue with the Server 2008 box. I'm assuming that the newer OS's or the clean installation of SQL server might be causing an issue but I'm only guessing at this point.

I've done a version check on all 3 instances of SQL Server using "SELECT @@VERSION" and have verified that all of the versions are 32 bit.

I've compiled my package on the Server 2003 box as well and it still won't install on the Server 2008 box. I've also set the Run64BitRuntime option to "False" in the package properties but so far nothing has helped.

Are there any files, such as dll's, that I need to transfer to the 2008 server from the 2003 server?

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: Check your .net frame work. Are they the same on all the machines?

Comment: What do you mean by "install"? Could you walk me through your process? What tasks and components are in the package that won't install? Can you create an empty package on the windows 7 machine and install it on the 2008 machine?

Comment: @rvphx The .net framework on my Win 7 box and the 2008 server are both v4.0.30319 while the 2003 server is 3.5. Do you think the newer .net version is causing the issue?

Comment: @billinkc What I mean by install is dbl clicking on the manifest file in the deploy folder of the package. This is when I get the error. The installation wizard won't launch. I've also imported the package into Integration Services and tried to run it from there but this causes the Execute Package Utility to stop working.

Answer (score 1):

As it turns out I needed to uninstall sql expess 2008. I'd read that sql server 2005 and sql express 2008 could exist on the same server which they can if they were only being used as database instances. Unfortunately the install of sql express 2008, which was already installed on the server, prohibited Integration Services and SQL Server Agent from working correctly and caused them to throw the errors mentioned.

Once sql express was uninstalled everything worked fine.

Thanks to everyone who responded.

Answer (score 0):

This looks like a build error for your package. You need to track down what component is represented by that "component with CLSID ..."

Usually if you add the package to a BIDS SSIS Project and Execute it (debug it) the component with the issue will become clear.